# Android - Kindle fire App developement with HTML5

Tags: android, html, image-processing, mobile-application, kindle-fire

I am going to start a project in HTML5 that will run in internet browsers. Further I want to use the same HTML5 code to develop a Kindle fire app for android devices.

I have two questions regarding this:

**Question 1** : Can we use the HTML5 code to develop Kindle fire app in Android devices. If we can How well it supports the navigators and device functionality.

**Question 2** : What is the image resolution for Kindle fire application. I have got several dimensions such as (1024x600, 600x800 and 525x640) but cant sure.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

to your first question: yes, the browser on the Ice Cream Sandwich based Fires is HTML5 compatible (it's webkit based). You can find the user agent strings at https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html#UserAgentStrings

The different models have different screen sizes and pixel densities. Those are documented on the same Specifications page as the UA Strings